# xml Soap request with node

Tags: node.js, xml, api, express, soap

I want to perform a soap request using Node

```
POST /booking/booking.asmx 
HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap12:Body>
        <showModuleType xmlns="http://example.es/">
          <user>string</user>
          <password>string</password>
        </showModuleType>
      </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>
```

to get response like this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <showModuleTypeResponse xmlns="http://exmaple.es/">
      <showModuleTypeResult>xml</showModuleTypeResult>
    </showModuleTypeResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

I tried the following packages but I am unable to get the requires respons

- easy-soap-request
- strong-soap
- request
- soap

Currently, I am using some weather API which is not free and will not work properly. But the code still has issues and the API code with the expected request and response are shown below

```
router.get('/try', function(req, res) {
        var os = require('os');
        if (os.platform() == 'win32') {
            var chilkat = require('chilkat_node10_win32');
        } else if (os.platform() == 'linux') {
            if (os.arch() == 'arm') {
                var chilkat = require('chilkat_node10_arm');
            } else if (os.arch() == 'x86') {
                var chilkat = require('chilkat_node10_linux32');
            } else {
                var chilkat = require('chilkat_node10_linux64');
            }
        } else if (os.platform() == 'darwin') {
            var chilkat = require('chilkat_node10_macosx');
        }
        //  Demonstrates how to do a SOAP request using the REST API.
        //  This example requires the Chilkat API to have been previously unlocked.
        //  See Global Unlock Sample for sample code.
        var rest = new chilkat.Rest();
        //  This is the request to be sent:

        /*
        POST /WeatherWS/Weather.asmx HTTP/1.1
        Host: wsf.cdyne.com
        Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
        Content-Length: length
        SOAPAction: "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityWeatherByZIP"
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
          <soap:Body>
            <GetCityWeatherByZIP xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
              <ZIP>string</ZIP>
            </GetCityWeatherByZIP>
          </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
        */
        //  Note: The application does not need to set the Host or Content-Length headers.
        //  Chilkat will automatically add these headers.

        //  Make the initial connection (without sending a request yet).
        var bTls = false;
        var port = 80;
        var bAutoReconnect = true;
        //  In this particular case, it is important to connect to "wsf.cdyne.com", not "ws.cdyne.com"...
        var success = rest.Connect("wsf.cdyne.com", port, bTls, bAutoReconnect);
        if (success !== true) {
            console.log(rest.LastErrorText);
            res.json("This example is correct in theory, but no longer works for live testing because the SOAP service provider (cdyne.com) has made changes or discontinued the free service.")
            return;
        }
        //  Add request headers:
        success = rest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        success = rest.AddHeader("SOAPAction", "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/GetCityWeatherByZIP");

        //  Build the SOAP XML request body.
        var soapXml = new chilkat.Xml();

        soapXml.Tag = "soap:Envelope";
        success = soapXml.AddAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        success = soapXml.AddAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        success = soapXml.AddAttribute("xmlns:soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");

        soapXml.NewChild2("soap:Body", "");
        success = soapXml.GetChild2(0);
        soapXml.NewChild2("GetCityWeatherByZIP", "");
        success = soapXml.GetChild2(0);
        success = soapXml.AddAttribute("xmlns", "http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/");
        soapXml.NewChild2("ZIP", "60187");
        soapXml.GetRoot2();

        console.log(soapXml.GetXml());

        //  Send the SOAP request
        var responseXml = rest.FullRequestString("POST", "/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx", soapXml.GetXml());
        if (rest.LastMethodSuccess !== true) {
            console.log(rest.LastErrorText);
            return;
        }

        //  When successful, the response status code will equal 200.
        if (rest.ResponseStatusCode !== 200) {
            //  Examine the request/response to see what happened.
            console.log("response status code = " + rest.ResponseStatusCode);
            console.log("response status text = " + rest.ResponseStatusText);
            console.log("response header: " + rest.ResponseHeader);
            console.log("response body (if any): " + responseXml);
            console.log("---");
            console.log("LastRequestStartLine: " + rest.LastRequestStartLine);
            console.log("LastRequestHeader: " + rest.LastRequestHeader);
            return;
        }

        var xml = new chilkat.Xml();
        success = xml.LoadXml(responseXml);

        //  GetXml will emit XML that is nicely indented for human viewing..
        console.log(xml.GetXml());

        //  A sample response XML is shown below...

        //  To get some information, use ChilkatPath.  For example...
        console.log("Temperature: " + xml.ChilkatPath("soap:Body|GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse|GetCityWeatherByZIPResult|Temperature|*"));
        console.log("Success.");


        /*
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <soap:Body>
                <GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse xmlns="http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/">
                    <GetCityWeatherByZIPResult>
                        <Success>true</Success>
                        <ResponseText>City Found</ResponseText>
                        <State>IL</State>
                        <City>Wheaton</City>
                        <WeatherStationCity>West Chicago</WeatherStationCity>
                        <WeatherID>10</WeatherID>
                        <Description>Mostly Sunny</Description>
                        <Temperature>33</Temperature>
                        <RelativeHumidity>39</RelativeHumidity>
                        <Wind>VRB5</Wind>
                        <Pressure>30.33F</Pressure>
                        <Visibility />
                        <WindChill />
                        <Remarks />
                    </GetCityWeatherByZIPResult>
                </GetCityWeatherByZIPResponse>
            </soap:Body>
        </soap:Envelope>
        */

});
```

Comment: Show the code you tried and response you got

Comment: @tbking I updated the question with code.